# Book - Woman left behind on an alien planet in a jungle turned into an alien

Tags: aliens, story-identification

I believe that I read this in the early 2010s when I was in New Jersey, although I might have read it as far back as the early 2000s when I was in Ohio (I remember checking it out from the library and reading it in my apartment, but I don't have a firm memory of the location). A female researcher is stranded on an alien planet, specifically in a jungle that's incredibly deadly due to environmental poisons and dangerous beasts. The local sapient aliens take pity on her and turn her into one of them. The aliens are quadrupedal with long tails, I think more like cats or lizards than monkeys. Their skin changes colors, I think both for camouflage and to express emotions. Eventually, other humans return to find her, and she's confronted with the question of whether she can become human again, and if she even wants to.

It was a B-format or Trade paperback, primarily white in color. I remember that the cover was almost garishly colorful, all primary colors, I think depicting the jungle itself. I think the title was four words, in the form of "The X of Y". For some reason, "The Color of Passion" comes to mind, but searching on that doesn't get me anything useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be ["The Color of Distance"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/466371.The_Color_of_Distance) by Amy Thomson, published in 1999?

Description:

> Juna is the sole survivor of a team of surveyors marooned in the dense and isolated Tendu rain forest, an uninhabitable world for humans. Her only hope for survival is total transformation--and terrifying assimilation--into the amphibian Tendu species. Juna will learn more about her own human nature than ever before.

As you can see, the cover does depict the jungle as well.

[image]

Comment: That's the one! Thank you. Was this a book that you were familiar with, or did you find it via searching?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Searching.  I guessed, given the description, that "The Color Of" might be a reasonable title start even if you misremembered the rest, so I google-searched "science fiction" "The Color Of" and restricted the search to site:goodreads.com to narrow down the possibility set... after that, it was just a matter of checking the first few that came up.

Comment: I should point out that this appears to be a rip-off of van Vogt's "The Enchanted Village" (or maybe "The Monster"). In that story a human dying of thirst comes across an ancient Martian city that does its best to save him, eventually by turning him into a Martian.